# Anime I watched as a kid on VHS where a girl draws a star to beat a computer virus-like enemy

Tags: corrector-yui

This anime is set in a Japanese town. One of the main characters is a girl with short brown hair. She went to high school and owned a special bracelet with special powers. Whenever she was in danger, she drew a star in the air and then her friend (or something) got bigger and everything so that he could beat the enemy. The enemy was some kind of computer virus I think.

Well, in one episode, that virus went into the telephone cable from the payphone, so it was connected with every phone in that town. Then the virus made the telephone ring, and when someone answered the phone, the person got sucked into the cables.

In another episode, that virus turned everything into gold.

In yet another episode, the director of the high school where the girl attended was possessed by that virus, so he ate everything he saw and turned into one awful creature — he walked in both arms and legs (like a dog), but his stomach was towards the ceiling (just like gymnastic figure "the bridge").

And there is one more thing, the opening video begins with the high school that the girl went to.

Answer (score 5):

It can be [**Corrector Yui**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrector_Yui)

[image: Pic]

> It is the year 2020 and computers have become an integral part of daily life for most people. However, a teenage girl Yui Kasuga is one of the few who cannot use computers at all, despite the fact that her father is a software developer. An evil computer called Grosser wants to take over the ComNet (what the Internet is called in Yui's time) and as the programs that have been developed to stop it (called "Correctors") need her help, she is sucked into the ComNet where she is recruited by a corrector called I.R., who gives her downloadable element suits that allow her to become the ComNet Fairy Corrector Yui who can fight Grosser's computer viruses.
>
> In the first season, the series revolves around the war against Grosser, and reveals the mysteries that surround the Correctors, their seemingly missing creator, and the relationship that he seems to have had with the corrupted computer.
>
> In the second season, Yui and the Correctors must fight with a mysterious virus who menaces the ComNet, and also cope with the mysterious Corrector Ai, a Corrector who tends to work on her own and seems to have her own agenda. The key to the mysteries seems to be a strange little girl who seems lost and may be related with the devastating virus appearances.